# How to make query on two different ontologies?

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

I have two different ontologies: one for movie genre and another for movie certification. I want to write a query in SPARQL that can find those movies having certification `x` (say `PG-13`) and genre `y` (say `action`). Both ontologies are different and I upload them in Apache Jena.

These are my ontologies:

```
PREFIX o2: <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/genre_ontology#>
PREFIX o1: <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/certification_ontology#>
```

I want to find movies having genre and certification. my query is

```
SELECT ?x ?z
WHERE {
    ?x o1:hasCertificationOf ?y.
   ?z o2:hasGenre ?a.

  FILTER regex(str(?y),"R_") FILTER regex (str(?a),"Adventure")
}
```

here `R` is `Restricted` certification

Query result contain movies in `x` and `z`, but i only want common movie in `x` and `z`?

Comment: what have you tried? how do you want to join the movies? based on their (exact same) title, based on a common id? add more details!

Comment: if you load both ontologies into the same Jena model, I don't see any problem. Just write the SPARQL query, Jena doesn't care about the origin of the triples.

Comment: These are my ontologies PREFIX o2: http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/genre_ontology# PREFIX o1: http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/certification_ontology#, i want to find movies having genre and certification. my query is SELECT ?x ?z WHERE { ?x o1:hasCertificationOf ?y. ?z o2:hasGenre ?a.

FILTER regex(str(?y),"R_") FILTER regex (str(?a),"Adventure") } here R is Restricted certification Query result contain movies in x and z, but i only want common movie in x and z?

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to provide a minimal example along with your question.

You might want to look at [Multiple triple patterns](http://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/current/sparql-tutorial.html#header3-35):

```
?s cert:level cert:PG13 .  
?s genres:genre genres:Action .
```

As you see, we use two namespaces (for 2 ontologies). You can reference them like this (before your SPARQL query):

```
PREFIX cert: <http://example.com/cert/1.0/>
PREFIX genres: <http://example.com/genres/1.0/>
```

Final query might look like this:

```
PREFIX cert: <http://example.com/cert/1.0/>
PREFIX genres: <http://example.com/genres/1.0/>

SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    ?s cert:level cert:PG13 .
    ?s genres:genre genres:Action .
}
```

**NB**: in order to apply multiple graph patterns in a single query, you must use the same variable in those patterns (`?s` in the last 2 graph patters).

I have no affiliation to the authors, but I think you might benefit from taking https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/linked-data.

Comment: These are my ontologies PREFIX o2: http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/genre_ontology# PREFIX o1: http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2016/11/certification_ontology#, i want to find movies having genre and certification. my query is SELECT ?x ?z WHERE { ?x o1:hasCertificationOf ?y. ?z o2:hasGenre ?a.

FILTER regex(str(?y),"R_") FILTER regex (str(?a),"Adventure") } here R is Restricted certification Query result contain movies in x and z, but i only want common movie in x and z?

Comment: do not use `x` and `z`, just use `x` in both patterns. updated my answer to highlight this.

Comment: by using x in both patterns, no result is coming.

Comment: that means there exists no such `x` that satisfies both rules.

Comment: but with my query, i am getting some name of movie that is common in both x and z.

Comment: In RDF, the subject ?s is always a URI (IRI more precisely). It's not enough to have the same movie name (it's an object) to have this match. If you're still struggling, provide some sample data and real queries in your question (you can edit it). The Stack Overflow community can't help you by guessing things.